# strange behavior in concurrently executing a function for objects in queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads

My program has a shared `queue`, and is largely divided into two parts:

**one** for pushing instances of class `request` to the `queue`, and **the other** accessing multiple `request` objects in the `queue` and processing these objects. `request` is a very simple class(just for test) with a `string req` field.

I am working on the second part, and in doing so, I want to keep one `scheduling thread`, and multiple (in my example, two) `executing threads`.

The reason I want to have a separate `scheduling thread` is to reduce the number of `lock` and `unlock` operation to access the `queue` by multiple `executing threads`.

I am using *pthread* library, and my scheduling and executing function look like the following:

```
void * sched(void* elem) {

    queue<request> *qr = static_cast<queue<request>*>(elem);

    pthread_t pt1, pt2;

    if(pthread_mutex_lock(&mut) == 0) {
        if(!qr->empty()) {
            int result1 = pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, execQueue, &(qr->front()));
            if (result1 != 0) cout << "error sched1" << endl;
qr->pop();
        }
        if(!qr->empty()) {
            int result2 = pthread_create(&pt2, NULL, execQueue, &(qr->front()));
            if (result2 != 0) cout << "error sched2" << endl;
qr->pop();
        }

        pthread_join(pt1, NULL);
        pthread_join(pt2, NULL);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    }

    return 0;
}

void * execQueue(void* elem) {

    request *r = static_cast<request*>(elem);
    cout << "req is: " << r->req << endl; // req is a string field

    return 0;
}
```

Simply, each of `execQueue` has one thread to be executed on, and just outputs a request passed to it through `void* elem` parameter.

`sched` is called in `main()`, with a thread, (in case you're wondering how, it is called in `main()` like below)

```
pthread_t schedpt;
int schresult = pthread_create(&schedpt, NULL, sched, &q);
if (schresult != 0) cout << "error sch" << endl;

pthread_join(schedpt, NULL);
```

and the `sched` function itself creates multiple(two in here) `executing threads` and `pop`s `request`s from the `queue`, and executes the `request`s by calling `execQueue` on multiple threads(pthread_create and then ptrhead_join).

The problem is the weird behavior by the program.

When I checked the size and the elements in the queue without creating threads and calling them on multiple threads, they were exactly what I expected.

However, when I ran the program with multiple threads, it prints out

1 items are in the queue.
2 items are in the queue.
req is: 
req is: FIRST! �(x'�j|1��rj|p�rj|1����FIRST!�'�j|!�'�j|�'�j| P��(�(��(1���i|p��i|

with the last line constantly varying.

The desired output is

1 items are in the queue.
2 items are in the queue.
req is: FIRST
req is: FIRST

I guess either the way I call the `execQueue` on multiple threads, or the way I `pop()` is wrong, but I could not figure out the problem, nor could I find any source to refer to for a correct usage.

Please help me on this. Bear with me for clumsy use of pthread, as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your queue holds *objects*, not pointers to objects. You can address the object at the front of the queue via `operator &()` as you are, but as soon as you pop the queue that object is gone and that address is no longer valid. Of course, `sched` doesn't care, but the `execQueue` function you *sent* that address do certainly *does*.

The most immediate fix for your code is this:

Change this:

```
pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, execQueue, &(qr->front()));
```

To this:

```
// send a dynamic *copy* of the front queue node to the thread
pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, execQueue, new request(qr->front()));
```

And your thread proc should be changed to this:

```
void * execQueue(void* elem) 
{
    request *r = static_cast<request*>(elem);
    cout << "req is: " << r->req << endl; // req is a string field
    delete r;
    return nullptr;
}
```

That said, I can think of better ways to do this, but this should address your immediate problem, assuming your `request` object class is copy-constructible, and if it has dynamic members, follows the [Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Comment: Thank you so much. I guessed that part was the problem, but could not see what the cause of the problem was. I am still not sure, so I am thinking about your solution. I am not sure why it is necessary to use an existing request object to create a request object.(Is there a better alternative that I could try?) Also, you said the queue is popped, the address is no longer valid. Is it because a pointer to a queue points to the address of the first element in the queue that is popped? Or is there another reason?

Comment: @user2418202 No. A queue is an abstract container adapter. It actually uses a generic container (usually a deque) for the underpinnings. Among other things, your queue content could be smart-pointers to dynamic objects rather than the objects themselves. Move construction is also possible, though I suspect if that were considerable you'd be nuts not to use the `std::thread` library in the first place, which makes most of these rather trivial. If I have time I'll post a shared-pointer queue strategy sample. Glad it helped, btw.

Comment: added a c++11 version for comparison/demonstration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19764772/85371

Comment: Thank you. I want to use c++11, but using pthread is required for this project. Can I ask one more question? Instead of `request` class, I am now passing multiple objects in a `struct` to pthread_create. How should I do this?

Comment: So long as the members support copy-construction and default assignment, you can just toss them in there. But refrain from any naked pointers in there. If you add members in that struct and even think about glancing your hand across the asterisk (`*`) on your keyboard, you're almost assuredly doing it wrong. [See this *very* brief article](http://klmr.me/slides/modern%2Dcpp.pdf) for the fundamental reasons why.

Answer (score 3):

And here's your mildly sanitized c++11 version just because I needed a simple test thingie for MSVC2013 installation :)

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a00880262e7809f)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <string>

struct request { std::string req; };

std::queue<request> q;
std::mutex queue_mutex;

void execQueue(request r) {
    std::cout << "req is: " << r.req << std::endl; // req is a string field
}

bool sched(std::queue<request>& qr) {
    std::thread pt1, pt2;

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(queue_mutex);
        if (!qr.empty()) {
            pt1 = std::thread(&execQueue, std::move(qr.front()));
            qr.pop();
        }
        if (!qr.empty()) {
            pt2 = std::thread(&execQueue, std::move(qr.front()));
            qr.pop();
        }
    }

    if (pt1.joinable()) pt1.join();
    if (pt2.joinable()) pt2.join();

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    auto fut = std::async(sched, std::ref(q));
    if (!fut.get()) 
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
}
```

Of course it doesn't actually do much now (because there's no tasks in the queue).